# How does topological properties of sets (openness, closed, compactness) matter in practical algorithm design for optimization problems?

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-methods, convex-optimization, numerical-optimization, math-software

In optimization problems, one places great emphasizes the properties of the constraint set

$$\min_{x \in \mathcal{C}} f(x)$$

For instance, when $\mathcal{C}$ is compact, we have the existence of an optimizer by Weierstrass, whereas when $\mathcal{C}$ is open or closed, we do not. Many algorithms such as gradient descent or other methods have properties depending on whether certain properties of $f$ are satisfied. Some functions such as $e^{-x}$ are not strongly convex, but it is locally strongly convex.

But in practice, we have a limitation on the largest number that can be represented in a computer. For instance, in C++, the largest number is unsigned integer is $18446744073709551616$. Hence every minimization problem solved in C++ is a constrained minimization problem over the compact set $$[-18446744073709551616, 18446744073709551616]^n$$

Ok, of course this is not the largest number that can be represented in a computer. It is a very large number $M$. The implications include all strictly convex functions are always locally strongly convex over a compact set $[-M, M]^n$, and every optimization problem are solved on this compact set as well.

My point is that we have a non-trivial loss of generality when solving problems on paper vs in a computer due to finite representation of numbers. Does it mean that the distinction between closed/open/compact, etc. are invalidated in practical algorithm design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, assumptions matter a lot. We need to know that any solution resulting from a floating-point algorithm must also solve the problem on the underlying space (e.g. $\mathbb{R}$). In a sense, the fact that the floating point numbers are compact may imply that some poorly-written optimization algorithms may terminate when they shouldn't. For instance, a minimization algorithm may tell you that the minimizer of $e^{-x}$ is $M$ (the number you've written above). However, the minimizer of this function **does not exist**! These sort of problems can arise when we do not check assumptions.

[The consequences can be **catastrophic** when we don't check the mathematical assumptions.](http://vectoranalysisgroup.com/journal_publications/jp26.pdf) In this article, not checking assumptions yielded a loss of **$700 million dollars and 3 years of work.**